# How to optimize a nested for loop

Tags: python

How can i optimize the nested for loop but still get the desired result?

```
from collections import defaultdict

class DataSet:
    def __init__(self,id):
        self.id = id
    def __repr__(self):
        return f"DATASET:{self.id}"

def function_test_1():
    result = defaultdict(list)
    matcher = {1: (1, 2, 3), 2: (3, 5, 7), 3: (12, 56, 4, 2), 4: (1, 3)}
    tomatch = (DataSet(1),DataSet(2),DataSet(3),DataSet(4))

    for t in tomatch:
        for m in matcher[t.id]:
            result[m].append(t)

    print(result)
```

Edit:

I want to match the list of DataSets (`tomatch`) to the list contained in `matcher`. The reference is the `DataSet.id` which is also the key of the `matcher` dict.

The expected result would be:

```
{
  1: [DATASET(1), DATASET(4)], 
  2: [DATASET(1), DATASET(3)], 
  3: [DATASET(1), DATASET(2), DATASET(4)], 
  5: [DATASET(2)], 
  7: [DATASET(2)], 
 12: [DATASET(3)], 
 56: [DATASET(3)], 
  4: [DATASET(3)]
}
```

Comment: "The result should be something like this:" - Why? What is the rule? Note that it would be easier to read with better chosen data.

Comment: @ThierryLathuille Thank you for the feedback i tried to make it clearer

Comment: Why do you want to eliminate that?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. I don't understand why you want to remove this loop, or why you believe that doing so would "optimize" anything. Generally, for optimization questions, we require objective standards and metrics.

Comment: @KellyBundy maybe eleminate is the wrong word. Optimize would fit better. It just really time intensive with more data

Comment: Then maybe don't use Python?

Comment: @KellyBundy thats not really helpful. I just want to learn how i can do this better.

Comment: But this already has optimal complexity and is also already pretty much optimal Python code. So if you want it significantly faster, you'll probably need something non-Python.

Comment: Since this is in the source code for the function, could you compile `result` ahead of time and insert it into the function definition?

Comment: @wjandrea the data changes. this is just to have an example